# how to connect form to web page (Sockets )

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I am new to vb.net (2010) and am working on a project that has to send information from a client application form to a php-based web page.  How could I accomplish that?

Would System.Net.Sockets work in my case? Could you show me an example?

Comment: more details : send (address number) from a (text box) to a php page and insert that in the database

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use sockets. The easiest way is to use HttpWebRequest to send data to web page, and HttpWebResponse to get the answer.

Look here for example: http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/mahesh/DownloadWebPage04252005073432AM/DownloadWebPage.aspx

Or search on Google for HttpWebRequest HttpWebResponse VB.